# Django: delete cookie from request

Tags: django

I know how to delete a cookie from response:

```
response = HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
response.delete_cookie("item_id")
return response
```

**But how to delete a cookie from request?**

I've a view that only has a request but not a response:

I'd like to delete the `cart_id` cookie when user arrives at my 'thanks.html' page.

```
def thanks(request):
    order_number = Order.objects.latest('id').id
    return render(request, 'thanks.html', dict(order_number=order_number))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't delete cookie from a request, or rather it would be an exercise in futility. The way you "delete" (and set) a cookie from the server side is by issuing a specific header on the response. The request only contains headers sent by the client.

All views have a response, it's just not super clear here because there's nothing named "response" but `render` always returns one.

> ## [`render()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#render)
>
> ```
> render(request, template_name, context=None, content_type=None, status=None, using=None)
> ```
>
> Combines a given template with a given context dictionary **and returns an HttpResponse object** with that rendered text.
>
> Django does not provide a shortcut function which returns a TemplateResponse because the constructor of TemplateResponse offers the same level of convenience as render().

(emphasis is mine)

So what you can do is update the generated response before it's returned to the user like so:

```
def thanks(request):
    order_number = Order.objects.latest('id').id
    response = render(request, 'thanks.html', dict(order_number=order_number))
    response.delete_cookie("item_id")
    return response
```